# webkitNotifications is undefined in chromium 44

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

Was `webkitNotifications` removed from Chromium? I've got `undefined` when I try to access `window.webkitNotifications` on Xubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should use the [new and standardized API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API) if you want to show notifications.